# MAMP Virtual Hosts not working properly, loading 'It Works!' page

Tags: apache, localhost, apache2, mamp, virtualhost

I had an issue last night where MAMP just refused to connect to the Apache server(unsure whether this has something to do with my issue). I decided to uninstall and reinstall. I was able to connect once again, however, when I added my virtual host to the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file in my MAMP folder, and navigate to it I get brought to a 'It works!' page.  (I also realised I get this page by typing `localhost` even without running MAMP?)

Below are some of my files

## httpd.conf(in MAMP)

```
//Uncommented line below
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

## httpd.conf(in MAMP)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName portfolio
    DocumentRoot '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portfolio'
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs'
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

## /private/etc/hosts

```
##
# Host Database
# localhost is used to configure the lookback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
127.0.0.1       portfolio
```

This is a copy paste of what I had before which worked 100%, unsure what happened between MAMP stopping working, the uninstall and reinstall. Is there an issue with apache somehow overwriting something? Really out of my depth here with this issue. Is there somewhere else I should be looking to debug this?

For reference, `localhost:8888` & `localhost:8888/portfolio` work as expected, `localhost/` & `portfolio/` don't, brings me to the 'It works!' page. Before this issue I was able to do 'localhost/phpmyadmin' to bring me to phpmyadmin and 'localhost/portfolio' to bring me to that directory, but neither of those work either. I've been wracking me brain for hours over this, watching tutorials and reading other answers but to no avail.

Anyone have any idea why this is occuring? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your Apache version? You only need `NameVirtualHost` before 2.3.11 (though it won't hurt anyway). Also, what's the output of `httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `Apache/2.4.18` and the output is `VirtualHost configuration:`, the value of just comes up blank for me.

Comment: Is there a chance that you are not editing the right files, or you are not doing it with the appropriate privileges (`sudo ...`) and the OS makes you think you succeeded writing? (Windows can do that, not sure about MacOS.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am almost 100% certain I have recreated the exact same steps as I had before. I am editing files within the `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache` directory. Is there any possibility that the `/private/etc/apache2` is somehow overwriting the MAMP configuration?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Also tried sudo and no luck, I just assume there is some outside source affecting this? Would removing apache help any, or would that only make matter worse?

Comment: `httpd -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES` shows parsed files (yet an easy way to determine whether a settings file is being used is to make an intentional syntax error). Unfortunately I've never used a Mac and I'm not very familiar with third-party Apache bundles so there isn't much else I can suggest.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I figured out a solution, thanks for your help, your assistance lead me down the road of solving my issue.

Answer (score 2):

So I eventually figured it out if anyone else has the same issue. I had forgotten previously that I had my localhost running on port 80. However when I tried that before my apache server wouldn't start on MAMP, the reason being was due to port 80 being used by `/private/etc/apache2`, so I used the answer to this question

https://superuser.com/questions/986775/how-can-i-remove-apache2-that-i-have-installed-in-mac-os-x

to remove apache. (Alternatively I guess you could just change the port number it listens to in the httpd.conf files?) I then changed my MAMP to listen to port 80 and this fixed my problem. Hope this helps anyone else with same issue

Comment: He he... That's indeed an extreme version of editing the wrong files—they don't even belong to the same program! :)